# Magento 2 : How to Add Custom Block to Admin Using Plugin

Tags: magento2, admin, plugin, shipment

In magento admin ‘`New Shipment`’ page, How can I add new custom block after the `‘Payment and Shipping Method’` block using plugin?

I have achieved this, using override technique by overriding Module_shipping core files. 
But I do not want this, because it can affect in future when Magento core is updated.

Thanks.

Comment: In the admin order page when creating new order?

Comment: yes. Basically when that page is loaded I need to insert my custom block.

Comment: At this location [...]/admin/admin/order_shipment/new/[...]

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: Plugins are interceptor used to enhance functionality.So do elaborate your objective when you say a custom block using plugin.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. What I want to achieve is that I need to insert a custom block  in 'New Shipment' page with some HTML elements on it (for example under 'Address Information' section I want to insert my custom htmls.).
 I have done this by overriding template files and blocks of core Shipping module for this.  
What I need to know is that how to do interceptor (plugin) to do the same thing without class overriding method.  Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone attempted to do similar thing to do on any other admin sections ? if so how did you accomplish that?